# SQL Server 2012 Intellisense Support for Extended Events

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 with SP1 for some reason when try to use extended events programmatically using T-SQL. I am not able to see intellisense working? Just trying to check is this something on my end or MS has yet to support intellisense for extended events and few other things.

Not able to find anything specific for extended events intellinsense support in [SQL Server BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934481.aspx)

For e.g. creating a new event session no events are popping up in intellisense for SQL Server? I know this was the case was SQL Server 2008 where intellisense was first introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't come across Intellisense support for XEs in SSMS yet. It ***will*** tell you when you have an error in your syntax (my common mistake was omitting `ON SERVER`). SQL Prompt 5 (latest version) has support for the control commands (`CREATE EVENT SESSION` ... `ALTER EVENT SESSION`, etc.) but not for the packages and events yet. For now I'd recommend just sticking with the metadata queries from [Jonathan Kehayias](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2010/12/02/an-xevent-a-day-2-31-querying-the-extended-events-metadata.aspx) to get a sense for the packages, events, predicates, maps, etc.

I think this is probably the case because Extended Events are still a work in progress and are undergoing such rapid change and development that more effort would have to be put into generating the Intellisense XML than they'd like to put into it until it's stabilized (from a feature perspective, not a reliability perspective).